# Autopopulate date form field using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In django I have a model named Perechi and to create the form I use ModelForm.
In model I define four date fields as: data_imperechere, primul_ou, data_ecloziune, data_inelare. Users must fill one of them for that other three fields to autopopulate. How can I write this in javascript? Or I must use jQuery? I have no experience in javascript.
So, to be more coincise I write an example:

```
data_imperechere = 2019-08-24
primul_ou = data_imperechere + 10
data_ecloziune = primul_ou + 18
data_inelare = data_ecloziune + 7
```

This example is when user fill data_imperechere. They can fill what field they want and other fields must be populated with calculated date.

Comment: Why would you need javascript for this at all? If you're using Django, you can just accept the form post, check which of the four fields is filled in, and then fill in the missing ones instead either as a preprocessing step in the view that handles the POST, or by overriding the model's `save` function (because I assume your model only saves the base date, not all four of them, if three of the dates are derivative). The only JS you need is the kind that disables "the other fields" when a user starts filling in any one of them.

Comment: How can I write the function to disable fields?

Comment: that question suggests you've never written any JS at all, in which case I would strongly recommend finding a modern JS tutorial and running through that, first. (given that modern JS has mostly obviated the need for jQuery). And if you see any mention of `alert` or `document.write`, or `onclick="..."`, find a better one, because that's a tutorial based on what was reasonable back in 1998 and are antipatterns in modern JS.

Comment: I have some knowledge of javascript but I don't know how to trigger the function. On onchange or which?

Comment: For standard JS you'd want `addEventListener("input", ...)` rather than "change" (don't use `onchange` or `oninput` element attributes, they're legacy syntax, and about as questionable as using python 2.7 syntax in a python 3 project. It might work, but you plain shouldn't)